# После Git LFS не работают файлы

Tags: git, dll, gitlab, git-push, git-pull

Добавил для репозитория Git LFS для управления файлами и указал на бинкрники по типу dll и so, по итогу после пуша на Gitlab и пула на сервер он не может запустить именно те файлы что указал в трекинге, Но файлы при этом есть. Если загружаю как обычные файлы то все отлично работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сервер-то в курсе про git-lfs?

Comment: У вас они symlink'и?! Конечно ничего так работать не будет. Заливать надо бинарники (скорее всего их имена типа `*.so.1.2.3`). Для проверки запустите `file libnode-module.so` там и там. Приведите вывод,только текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Судя по размерам это заглушки git lfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После пула на сервер помогло git lfs pull